# Sympy polynomials with `mpfr` coefficients?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, polynomial-math, gmpy

I want to use Sympy's polynomials, but I also want to use higher-precision coefficients.

Just Doing It seems to give me polynomials with `sympy.core.numbers.float` coefficients.

```
import sympy
from sympy import Poly
from sympy.abc import x
from gmpy2 import mpfr, get_context

get_context().precision = 150

#float64 can't tell this from 1.0
one_and_change = mpfr('1.0000000000000000000000000000000000001')
#mpfr('1.0000000000000000000000000000000000001000000005',150)

p = [one_and_change]
px = Poly(p, x)

print(px)
# Poly(1.0, x, domain='RR')
print(px.is_one)
# True
print(type(px.all_coeffs()[0]))
# <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
```

I've also tried `sympy.mpmath.mpf`, with the same results.

This also didn't work:[[1](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/polys/internals.html#sympy.polys.domains.RealField)]

```
domain = sympy.polys.domains.realfield.RealField(150)
px = Poly(p, x, domain=domain)
print(type(px.all_coeffs()[0]))
# <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
```

Comment: You can probably use `domain='EX'` with `Float`.

Comment: I don't think so. `Float` is Python-sized fixed-width IEEE floating point, isn't it?

Comment: No, Float is a wrapper around mpmath.mpf, which is arbitrary precision.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out thanks to looking for a way to set its precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few obstacles:

- `gmpy.mpfr` has no `._sympy_` method, so it will be converted to float in an intermediate step.
- `sympy.Poly`, by default, uses `sympy.polys.domain.RR` for floating point coefficients, and will use it to convert.
- `RR`, when it loads, uses 53 as its precision, and ignores `mpmath.mp.precision`.
- When converting, `RR` uses `RR.precision` and ignores the argument's precision.

Solution:

1. Coefficients must be a Sympy type (e.g. `sympy.Float`, which has extended precision).
2. For the domain, one of the following:

   - Set `sympy.polys.domain.RR._context.prec = my_precision`.
   - Pass `domain='EX'`, which doesn't do conversion.
   - Pass in a custom domain (such as `sympy.polys.domains.realfield.RealField(150)`).

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Most of these should be considered bugs.

Comment: I consider the first an obvious missing feature. Second is fine, except that it leads to the others. Not sure about the third. I think the fourth should be considered a bug, but maybe there's a reason for it.